# Heroku Deployment : M.E.R.N Stack application only works locally even after deploying to Heroku

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, deployment

When I run the command Heroku open in Git, Heroku will serve the Login page only and won't allow the "Login With Spotify" button to route to the Spotify Oauth page onClick.

I also get the error "xhr.js:178 GET http://localhost:3000/auth/spotify net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED in the developer console.

The app only works locally when I run nodemon server to start the Node.js side(http://localhost:3000) and yarn start on the React client-side(http://localhost:3001). If those two servers aren't running Heroku will not properly deploy my app.

[Application view after Heroku open is executed through Git](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvQnR.png)

[Developer console error that occurs onClick to the "Login With Spotify" button without the servers running on Heroku open](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcblD.png)